# VBA listbox select worksheet by index

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a form with listbox which dynamically provides a list of the worksheets in the current workbook (code below).  I wish to take the selected Sheet and refer to it in a formula later in the process.  From hours of playing around I cannot seem to accomplish this. I believe I read somewhere that you cannot take the string back to the sub and use it to refer to to an object.  So I thought maybe I can create two listboxes

1. for sheet name
2. for sheet index

that I could pass the index number to and maybe use that in my formula to lookup items from the correct sheet.

For the life of my I cannot seem to find a way to connect the two since the items will always be changing; the code will be ran on multiple workbooks by multiple operators so the layout will most likely change between users. I can easily add the second list box with index #'s but I have a block on how to associate the name which will have meaning to the user and the index which I can pass back to the sub. I realize the "On click" procedure for the list box to associate the two but with the dynamic nature of the fields I cannot come up with the logic to put that into code.

```
For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name
    End With
Next N
```

Comment: You can refer to the sheet using name as well as index. What are you wanting to get done by getting the string of the selected item? i.e. `Msgbox(Worksheets(selectedItemFromList).Name)`

Comment: I thought I could add it to a formula to refer to the worksheet (where xxxxxxxx represents the choice from the listbox):  
Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R7C5," & xxxxxxx & "!R1C1:R65000C8,2,FALSE)"
I should mention I am passing the the sheet selected back to the sub in a variable type: string.

Comment: You are building the formula using string. So, I am not sure why would that not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out.

Declare a public variable above the code for the UserForm, making it available throughout your workbook from any module or code.

```
Public listChoice As String
```

Using your code to get the sheet names for the ListBox rowsource.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count
        With ListBox1
            .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).name
        End With
    Next n

End Sub
```

Including an update event for the ListBox

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()

    listChoice = ListBox1.Text

End Sub
```

I included a test just to demonstrate that the result is still retained.  You don't need this, it demonstrates the results on the screenshot.

```
Private Sub cmdTestChoice_Click()

    MsgBox ("The choice made on the ListBox was: " & listChoice)

End Sub
```

**edit:** To access that sheet later, you can call it using something like this:

Some examples of different ways to access a cell, using .Range, or .Cells, with numbers or letters.

Using lRow & lCol as Long to set row and column numbers.

```
Sheets(listChoice).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = TextBox1.Value  'Set cell on sheet from TextBox
TextBox2.Value = Sheets(listChoice).Range("A2").Value        'Set TextBox From Cell on Sheet
'Set a cell on another sheet using the selected sheet as a source.
Sheets("AnotherSheet").Cells(lRow, "D") = Sheets(listChoice).Range("D2")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yes, I happen to have a sheet named Stan, no big whoop.

Comment: Thanks so Much.  I have a very similar set up.  Now when I bring back the public variable, in this case "listchoice".  How can I get VBA to use this as a worksheeet?  At this point the user is wanting to lookup data which is residing on sheets[listchoice].

Comment: see the revised answer to get some examples of using the variable in a worksheet declaration to set values. Using `Sheets("sheetName")`, the expected type for a sheet name is a string anyway, so it fits nicely.

Comment: Thanks so Much.  Now I see my problem was related more to the reference in the formula. Your work validated my idea was in the right direction.  I did not place the .name after the variable in myVlookup.

Comment: That's great.  I'm glad to hear you were already headed in that direction.  Just as a tip, check out the Locals Window when debugging, it tells you what type things are and their values as you step through the code.  No insult meant if you already knew about it.  You can see how everything is accessed.

Comment: No insult taken...Your help was greatly appreciated. I have a lot to learn.